# FileReader ou alternativa para IE9

Tags: javascript

O objeto FileReader permite aplicações web ler assincronamente o conteúdo dos arquivos (ou buffers de dados puros) do computador do usuário. Os seguintes browser suportados são:

```
Firefox (Gecko) - 3.6 (1.9.2) 
Chrome - 7 
Internet Explorer - 10     
Opera - 12.02
Safari - 6.0.2
```

Estou desenvolvendo uma importação onde leio um arquivo e transformo ele em base64 isso para IE10 funciona perfeitamente, preciso da mesma solução para IE9.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu o seu problema?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode verificar se FileReader  esta habilitado para o navegador e caso não esteja utilizar uma opção alternativa:

```
if ('FileReader' in window) {
  // Faça algo se FireReader for suportado
} else {
  // Faça algo caso o FireReader não for suportado.
}
```

Possivel solução compativel com IE8 > [FileReader](https://github.com/Jahdrien/FileReader)
   Lembrando, esta solução utiliza jQuery e Flash.

Referencia: [How to get Cross Browser Compatibilty for window.fileReader API of HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541611/how-to-get-cross-browser-compatibilty-for-window-filereader-api-of-html5)

Comment: Vi que existe o ActiveXObject seria uma solução melhor?

Answer (score 2):

Conforme a documentação do [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) da *API File* é suportada pelos seguintes navegadores:

- Chrome versão 13
- Firefox (Gecko) versão 3.0 (1.9)
- Internet Explorer versão 10.0
- Opera versão 11.5 (Presto)
- Safari (WebKit) versão 6.0

Então nativamente você não vai conseguir resolver isto, pois é uma limitação (não havia sido implementado ainda), no entanto existem *fallbacks*, por exemplo em Flash.

> Muitos ficam falando o Flash vai morrer ou morreu, ok concordo, mas isso é um caso de desuso e não que morreu de verdade, ainda em *Desktops* você pode usa-lo como *fallback* para várias coisas

Um exemplo de ótimas alternativas:

- https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js
- https://github.com/Jahdrien/FileReader (usando totalmente flash)
- https://github.com/moxiecode/moxie
- https://github.com/mailru/FileAPI

Veja mais *Polyfills* no repositório do *Modernizr*:

- https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro gostaria de lhe lembrar da maior conquista nos ultimos anos:

[Internet Explorer End of Support](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/WindowsForBusiness/End-of-IE-support?tduid=(31ebd1a50ef4a169d2634092e42a6e06)(256380)(2459594)(TnL5HPStwNw-u3G0ms9hhVi8CFRuR4fomQ)())

Então por que dá suporte à um browser que não é mais suportado pelo fabricante?

Em todo caso, você pode usar um Polyfill para o File API:

- [FileReader](https://github.com/Jahdrien/FileReader)
- [moxie](https://github.com/moxiecode/moxie)

Comment: Vi que existe o ActiveXObject seria uma solução melhor?

Comment: Se você não quiser dá suporte aos outros navegadores, tais como Chrome, Opera, Firefox e MS Edge, é uma opção, porem não recomendo

Comment: Você teria um exemplo de como implementar usando o ActiveXObject? Pois sempre da o erro "O servidor de automação não pode criar objeto”.